# Appening Bulk of JSON Data From Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

In jQueryMobile and PhoneGap project I got more than 1000 of data in JSON format. 
The problem am facing that; Need to fetch all the data with in minumum time.
So for this purpose ; currently am using Fetching data in Scroll Up event using jQueryMobile iScrollview.
[jquery-mobile-iscrollview](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview)

Is there any method instead of that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ajax to fetch your data block by block after the page is loaded. This won't block your UI. And when you scroll your page, as the data is already fetched, user needn't to wait.
I am not sure whether this answer fit your needs.

Comment: @ Franky Yang : Can you please share one of its example? or any reference link?